Using content-[attr()] doesn't work on hover
I want to add some paragraph in the content, when I hover to the element in Tailwind CSS. Here is my code:
const myText = "This a Paragraph for Testing css Tailwind";

<div className='bg-blue-700 hover:after:content-[attr(myText)] hover:after:text-[30px]'>
  Before
</div>

However, it doesn't work. How can I a long paragraph instead writing This_is_Paragraph_...

Maybe you need to add it as attribute? <div myText="..." className="..." >... . css attr reads from the element attributes, you have to pass it as attribute to the div.

"it doesn't work." is not a valid question - Please have a look at the [tour], [ask] and how to create a [mre]

With the attr() method, you can only reference an HTML attribute directly on the current element. Therefore, the value of the myText variable needs to be assigned to a myAttr attribute, which you can then reference as attr(myAttr).

Referencing an attribute value - TailwindCSS Docs



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div myAttr="This is example" class='after:content-[attr(myAttr)]'>
  Before
</div>



